# Why does Snowflake DBMS say there is no current schema when I have a DEFAULT_NAMESPACE set on my user?

Tags: sql, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I connect to the Snowflake DBMS and run a SQL statement, I get an error message saying that I have no current schema (i.e. I've not run a `USE SCHEMA <schema name>` statement, or used a [JDBC] connection string that specifies a default schema).

My user has been created with a `DEFAULT_NAMESPACE` so why isn't this used to provide the current/default database and schema for object names in my statements?

Comment: Is your DEFAULT_NAMESPACE containing a fully-qualified schema name in the form of <db_name>.<schema_name>?

Comment: Is this being run from a Client which is using the JDBC driver? If yes, can you share the screenshot of connection parameters being passed and the error message?

Comment: @Sergiu yes, the DEFAULT_NAMESPACE on the user definition is set to `<database>.<schema>`, specifically `DFTEST.PUBLIC`.

Comment: @SrinathMenon the JDBC URL is this: `jdbc:snowflake://mxcbejc-ve65864.snowflakecomputing.com/?DB=dftest`. As you can see I'm not providing a `SCHEMA=<schema name>` in the connection string BUT the user does have `DEFAULT_NAMESPACE=DFTEST.PUBLIC` set, so why doesn't this get used in statements?

Answer (score 0):

The schema needs to be passed with the full path of `<database>.<schema>`. Maybe here is the error?

If not, can you please share the corresponding code?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-user.html

Comment: do you mean in the user's `DEFAULT_NAMESPACE` or in the SQL/DML statement? I'm not prefixing the object name in the DML, but I was expecting the `DEFAULT_NAMESPACE` to provide this fully qualified name. E.g. if I execute `SELECT * FROM table1` and `DEFAULT_NAMESPACE` is set to `DFTEST.PUBLIC` then I'd expect the query to run fine (expanding to `SELECT * FROM DFTEST.PUBLIC.table1` but, as I've not executed a `USE SCHEMA PUBLIC` then the statement fails (no current schema).